# what is the right lexing strategy regarding data structures

Tags: javascript, parsing, data-structures, lex, chevrotain

I created a data structure for a framework I'm working on. it look like this

```
version: 1.0
name: Joshua Kensington
type: Doctor
media: http://some.page.com/media
color: #ffe339
```

This data structure currently has a specific set of known keys and well-defined value types for each and I tend to make this data structure into a standard so it might be expended, meaning that there might be more keys or more values that will be added in later versions.

I'm using `chevrotain` framework to create a lexer and a parser and I was struggling to figure out which is the best approach.

I've came up with these:

- tokenizing the structure as a `key: value` set where keys will be defined as "key" token, the colon will be "colon" and the value will be a general "string literal" token.
  the parser will cunsume `{key}{colon}{string literal}`
  That way I can add more keys and values later on but I will have to create a new component that will validate the data against the version definition
- tokenizing the structure as `key: value type` set where keys will be defined as "key" and colon as "colon" but for each value type, I will create a token of its own: a boolean, a url, a color, string, sets etc.
  this will give me a better control over the allowed types but I still wouldn't be able to strict value types to certain keys
- tokenizing each known key separately and each value type and let the parser define the allowed combinations.
  This will spare me the validation process but it will add an overhead for each time the data structure definition will change

I thought that it is not that bad if users will add unknown keys because the data structure version will ensure that the keys that supposed to be there, will be there. also, I want to support missing keys when they are irrelevant (like when the users won't add "media" key if they don't use it)

So, what is the accepted standard regarding lexing data structures like this, are there any other strategies or is there a rule of thumb regarding this matter?

Comment: Are you talking about a *data structure* or about a *string serialisation*? You maybe should separate the two. Specify a schema for the structure (key names, types, semantics), then just use a YAML parser and validate the data against your schema.

Comment: Thanks Bergi, the question was in general about lexing and parsing data structure. The data structure I’m working on is not yaml, it has a different structure, but you gave me an idea to check out how yaml lexing was configured

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a proper guide or article so I came up with a solution that seems reasonable for who it may be of value

- I configured my laxer to properly tokenize all known keys so the parser could verify against the definition version.
- I also tokenized proper value types and the parser is validating them according to each key allowed type.
- I also allowed unknown `key:value` pairs for foreword compatibility. they are obviously not being validated but value types are being tokenized.
- I added a support for "missing" keys where they are not needed (up to the user decision).